# Wordpress Customizer Not Setting Custom Settings or Controls

Tags: theme-customizer

I've been learning how to created theme customizer feature to a theme. I have been learning how to make social media icons to show up in the footer.

I have included the files that have to be included in the function.php. But in front-end of theme customizer, my setting does not show up and getting an error message.

I'm learning from just want to see if would work see: https://www.competethemes.com/blog/social-icons-wordpress-menu-theme-customizer/#comment-20708

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'rixcy_scripts' not found or invalid function name in /Users/brandonpowell/sites/valet/alter-theme/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Footer.php

```
<?php
?>

<!-- #content -->
<div class="footer">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="width-6">
                <img src="img/AlterEgo-Branding-text-color.png">
        </div>

        <div class="width-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="social">
        <div class="main-content">
                <?php require get_template_directory() . '/inc/outputicons.php'; ?>
        </div>
</div>


<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

socialcustomizersection.php

```
  <?php
        function my_add_customizer_sections( $wp_customize ) {
    
            $social_sites = ct_atlers_social_array();
    
            // set a priority used to order the social sites
            $priority = 5;
    
            // section
            $wp_customize->add_section( 'ct_alter_social_array_filter', array(
                'title'       => __( 'Social Media Icons', 'alter' ),
                'priority'    => 12,
                'description' => __( 'Add the URL for each of your social profiles.', 'alter' )
            ) );
    
            // create a setting and control for each social site
            foreach ( $social_sites as $social_site => $value ) {
    
                $label = ucfirst( $social_site );
    
                if ( $social_site == 'google-plus' ) {
                    $label = 'Google Plus';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'twitter' ) {
                    $label = 'Twitter';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'facebook' ) {
                    $label = 'Facebook';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'Github' ) {
                    $label = 'github';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'linkedin' ) {
                    $label = 'Linkedin';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'youtube' ) {
                    $label = 'Youtube';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'instagram' ) {
                    $label = 'Instagram';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'instagram' ) {
                    $label = 'Instagram';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'dribbble' ) {
                    $label = 'dribbble';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'behance' ) {
                    $label = 'behance';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'behance' ) {
                    $label = 'behance';
                } elseif ( $social_site == 'email-form' ) {
                    $label = 'Contact Form';
                }
                // setting
                $wp_customize->add_setting( $social_site, array(
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw'
                ) );
                // control
                $wp_customize->add_control( $social_site, array(
                    'type'     => 'url',
                    'label'    => $label,
                    'section'  => 'ct_tribes_social_media_icons',
                    'priority' => $priority
                ) );
                // increment the priority for next site
                $priority = $priority + 5;
            }
        }
        add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_add_customizer_sections' );
```

outputicons.php

```
<?php

function my_social_icons_output() {

    $social_sites = ct_atlers_social_array();

    foreach ( $social_sites as $social_site => $profile ) {

        if ( strlen( get_theme_mod( $social_site ) ) > 0 ) {
            $active_sites[ $social_site ] = $social_site;
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $active_sites ) ) {

        echo '<ul class="social-media-icons">';
        foreach ( $active_sites as $key => $active_site ) {
            $class = 'fa fa-' . $active_site; ?>
            <li>
                <a class="<?php echo esc_attr( $active_site ); ?>" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( $key ) ); ?>">
                    <i class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $active_site ); ?>"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

socialarray.php

```
<?php
function ct_atlers_social_array() {

    $social_sites = array(
        'twitter'       => 'alter_twitter_profile',
        'facebook'      => 'alter_facebook_profile',
        'google-plus'   => 'alter_googleplus_profile',
        'linkedin'      => 'alter_linkedin_profile',
        'youtube'       => 'alter_youtube_profile',
        'instagram'     => 'alter_instagram_profile',
        'dribbble'      => 'alter_dribbble_profile',
        'behance'       => 'alter_behance_profile',
        'github'        => 'alter_github_profile',
        'email_form'        => 'alter_email_profile',
    );

    return apply_filters( 'ct_alter_social_array_filter', $social_sites );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `section` you created `'Social Media Icons'` doesn't show because is empty it doesn't have any control, this is because you didn't set the correct `ID` in the control arguments, it should be like this in `socialcustomizersection.php`:

```
// control
$wp_customize->add_control( $social_site, array(
    'type'     => 'url',
    'label'    => $label,
    'section'  => 'ct_alter_social_array_filter', //it should be the ID you Set for the section
    'priority' => $priority
) );
```

also in `footer.php` you are loading `outputicons.php` and that only contains a function, you need to call the `function`, put this after the `require_once` on the `footer.php` or at the end of `outputicons.php`:

```
my_social_icons_output();
```

the section will show, i added 2 here for testing the output:

[image]
and they work:

[image]

Comment: This the right way to called a function I may ask. `<?php require_once my_social_icons_output();  ?>`

Comment: `require_once` its used for loading `files`, you can just `<?php my_social_icons_output(); ?>` given that you are loading the file with the function in `functions.php`